# Blackberry Facebook SDK, encountering 403 Forbidden when posting status update

Tags: facebook, blackberry, sdk

I want to integrate Facebook with my Blackberry app. For that I have downloaded the Facebook SDK for Blackberry. I am using the following code for posting status to the User' FB:

```
String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
String APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
String APPLICATION_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;              

ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);

try{
 User user = fb.getCurrentUser();
 String result = user.publishStatus("Hello world!");
 if ((result != null) && !result.trim().equals("")) {
    Dialog.inform("Publish Success.");
 } else {
    Dialog.inform("Publish Failed.");
 }

}catch(FacebookException fe){
  fe.printStackTrace();
}
```

The log in is successful, it is returning to my application properly and getting the user details in json format also. But when `publishStatus()` is fired, process is failed. Here is debug window details on `publishStatus()` operation.

```
2012-02-07 10:46:51 [INFO] HTTP-POST (TCP WIFI):  https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/feed;interface=wifi
2012-02-07 10:46:51 [INFO] HTTP-POST Response:  403 Forbidden
2012-02-07 10:46:51 [INFO] HTTP-POST Body:  text/javascript; charset=UTF-8(0)
```

What is reason for the 403 forbidden error? Is the access token should be with this above URL? If it is, how to integrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to change the permission and problem is solved.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS;
```